# 64-bit G++ 4.6.3 doesn't treat longs as long longs in specialised function templates, even though they're the same size. Is this a bug?

Tags: c++, g++, template-specialization, function-templates, long-long

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cinttypes>  

template<class T>
void f();

template<>
inline void f<long long>() {
  std::cout<<"f<long long>()"<<std::endl;
}

int main(int , char** ) {
  std::cout<<"sizeof(long)="<<sizeof(long)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"sizeof(long long)="<<sizeof(long long)<<std::endl;
  f<int64_t>();
  return 0;
}
```

32-bit G++ 4.6.3 compiles this successfully and produces the output:

```
sizeof(long)=4
sizeof(long long)=8
f<long long>()
```

Compiling under 64-bit G++ 4.6.3 however produces the linker error:

```
undefined reference to `void f<long>()'
ld returned 1 exit status
```

even though compiling and running with the `f<int64_t>()` line commented out produces:

```
sizeof(long)=8
sizeof(long long)=8
```

Is there a good reason why 64-bit G++ treats `f<long>` and `f<long long>` as different functions, even though `long` and `long long` are the same size, or is this a bug that I should report?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying type of `int64_t` can be anything that meets the requirements. It's okay to make it `long` on one platform and `long long` on another.

Since you provide a specialization for `long long` and the generic version has no body, if `int64_t` is not a `long long` you get an undefined reference.

And yes, there is a good reason why `f<long>` and `f<long long>` are different functions: it's because the standard says that `long` and `long long` are distinct types. The fact that they happen to be the same width on some platform doesn't matter, especially because they may be of different widths on another.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the standard says they're distinct types. This makes sense, as otherwise 32-bit G++ would not be able to use long for 32-bit ints and long long for 64-bit ints, but it causes an annoying incompatibility when mixing code that uses QT's qint64 with code that uses int64_t, as under 64-bit G++ qint64=long long, and int64_t=long. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

They are different types, so they have to be treated differently. The size of the types does not affect overloading or template selection.

Your problem might be that `int64_t` is `long` on one system and `long long` on the other. That's a problem when combining typedefs with overloads or templates.