# Should I use long long or int64_t for portable code?

Tags: c++, c, types, int64, long-long

I have an open-source codebase that is written in both C and C++. I'm looking for an integer type that is guaranteed to be *at least* 64 bits wide, which can be reliably compiled on most OS X (Intel, 64-bit) and Linux boxes with open-source C and C++ compilers, without too much extra work on the end user's part. Windows and 32-bit client support are not important at this time.

I did some testing on OS X, and the latest GCC that ships with the developer tools does not support C+11 mode (and therefore does not seem to guarantee availability of `long long`). Clang does not support this, either, though it supports `long long` if C99 mode is enabled, after a certain version.

Is the general suggestion to use `int64_t` in place of `long long`, when portability is an important goal? Using the format specifiers seems painful.

Can I reliably cast an `int64_t` to `long long` (and likewise to the `unsigned` equivalent with `uint64_t`) to use it with existing functions and libraries that take `long long` as parameters? (And back again, of course.)

In that frame of mind, if I ship code that requires Clang functionality not in GCC, is Clang going to replace GCC as the compiler of choice on Linux? Is that compiler something I can expect, for the most part, when offering source code to end users?

Basically, I'd like to ask for some advice from other developers who have used both types for portable C and C++ code, who might have some suggestions on what might be the better long-term way to go, given the above goal in mind.

Comment: gcc has had `long long` as an extension before c++11, so as long as you don't disable gcc-extensions you should be fine with using `long long` on gcc (Actually I don't think I've used/seen a compiler not offering long long for a long time).

Comment: Note that `int64_t` can have underlying type `long` or `long long` among others, which can cause portability issues if overloading is needed.

Comment: Also consider typedef to make easy changes from platform to platform.

Comment: One thing to consider is that using overloads or templates with `int64_t` might select different versions on different systems. See [this other question on int64_t vs long vs long long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463402/64-bit-g-4-6-3-doesnt-treat-longs-as-long-longs-in-specialised-function-templ)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The types `long long` and `unsigned long long` are standard C and standard C++ types each with at least 64 bits. All compilers I'm aware of provide these types, except possibly when in a `-pedantic` mode but in this case `int64_t` or `uint64_t` won't be available with pre-C++ 2011 compilers, either. On all of the systems `<stdint.h>` is available, too.  That is, as far as I can tell it doesn't matter much how you spell the type. The main goal of `<stdint.h>` is to provide the best match for a specific number of bits. If you need at least 64 bit but you also want to take advantage of the fasted implementation of such a type, you'd use `int_least64_t` or `uint_least64_t` from `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>` (in case of the latter, the names are defined in namespace `std`).

Comment: I would sure like the standard to add a bigger type such as 128 or more, considering that in this day where cryptography is used a lot, you need such a type so you don't have to rely on many libraries.

Comment: I haven't seen a proposal for such a type (`long long long`?) although I'm aware that many system actually support 128 bit types by way of SIMD support: Send a proposal to WG14 and/or WG21!

Comment: `long long long` isn't necessary; a system that supports 128-bit integers can define *extended integer types* and define `int128_t` and `uint128_t` in terms of those types.

Comment: if the OP wants the fastest type with at least 64 bits, `int_fast64_t` and `uint_fast64_t` will be better

Answer (score 31):

> Is the general suggestion to use `int64_t` in place of `long long`, when portability is an important goal?

I'd be very surprised if a compiler offered `int64_t` but not `long long`.

If `long long` is present, it must have at least 64 bits, so casting from `(u)int64_t` to `(unsigned) long long` is value-preserving.

If you need a type with *exactly* 64 bits, use `(u)int64_t`, if you need *at least* 64 bits, `(unsigned) long long` is perfectly fine, as would be `(u)int_least64_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Use int64_t.  int64_t means 64 bits and you'll get 64 bits wherever you go.  long long is actually as implementation dependent as long is.  That is, a long long has to be bigger than or equal to a long, but that could be different depending on the compiler and platform.

Comment: There is a guarantee in the standards that `long long` must be at least 64 bits. It may be longer, but it cannot be shorter. So, no, it's not as implementation dependent as `long`: For `long` the rule is, that it only needs to be as long as `int`, which only needs to be bigger than `char`. So, you could have a platform with `sizeof(long) == 2`, but `sizeof(long long) >= 8` must be true on every platform.

Comment: Thank you.  That's good to know. But in the very least the sizeof(long long) is still platform dependent and the only way to go to get consistent 64 bits is int64_t.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about "an integer type that is guaranteed to be at *least* 64 bits wide". And that's precisely what `long long` delivers.

Comment: The OP was talking about portable, and so I'd go for the fixed size: int64_t.  It says 64 bits, so you don't even have to think about it.

Comment: `long long` is portable as its part of the standard. And if you don't have a `long long`, you'll extremely likey not have an `int64_t` either.

Comment: For years MS did not have long long, and used a native __int64 to get 64 bits and for a bit even to define __int64_t.  Not sure when they got long long.