# Overflow with integer

Tags: c++, types, data-conversion

I want to convert the number from decimal to hexadecimal number. The problems is the number is too big that cannot store in int datatype.For example,

```
int a = pow(10,17);
```

However, if I try to use double, I will face the problem of modulo operator because it does not support floating point datatype.

What should I do to convert it and store it? (Project Euler Problem Number 162).

Comment: Why not use `long`? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/900245/836214

Comment: How about `unsigned long int`?

Comment: Even long int cannot store such of very big data, pow(10,17)

Comment: If a 64-bit datatype such as `unsigned long long` can't handle it, you have to use a library such as [gmplib](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: What is gmplib library?

Comment: If it's only because you have doubles, can't you use `fmod`?

Comment: Regarding what you try to do (convert decimal to hexadecimal), can't you just print the numbers as hexadecimal? And if you have a normal `int` variable you try to convert (and you have to do it yourself, and not use e.g. `snprintf`) then it's just a couple of simple bitwise operations needed (masking and shifting) together with a comparison.

Comment: @MakaraPr _'Even long int cannot store such of very big data, pow(10,17)'_ Note that 2^64 is way bigger than 10^17! If you work with `unsigned long long` your results should fit in well there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use can use `long` for that

To know the difference go
[Difference between long and int data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900230/difference-in-long-vs-int-data-types-in-c/900245#900245)

You can convert `int to long` simply by

```
long variable=(long)a;
```

If that don't meet your requiremnet

You can use `long long` [long long in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c)

Conversion:

```
long long variable = (long long) a;
```

Comment: On some platforms (e.g. Windows) `long` is the same size as `int`.

Comment: then he can use long long

Comment: He can use int64_t if he uses C++11. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: @olevegard: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468281/should-i-use-long-long-or-int64-t-for-portable-code

Comment: @SajadLfc `long long` isn't part of the standard though( as far as I can tell ) But yeah, but since `long long` is at least 64 bytes it should be the best choice if `C++11` is not an option