# 64 bit integers and older C++ compilers

Tags: c++, types, portability, int64, long-long

I want to use 64 bit integers in my C++ code. I understand I can either `#include <cstdint>` and then declare a `uint64_t` or use `unsigned long long` (or the equivalent for signed versions).

However, it appears that support for this was not added until `C++11` and I would like my code to be compatible with compilers that don't have full C++11 support.

What is a good portable way to support 64 bit integers in C++?

Comment: There's probably a Boost library for this

Comment: [uint64_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) is optional, even with C++11, so that is not portable either.

Comment: Are you looking for things like `uint64_t`, `uint32_t`, etc or specifically `uint64_t`?

Comment: @Justin I am specifically interested in 64 bit integers.

Comment: Do you need something guaranteed 64 bit or are you okay with at least 64 bit support?

Comment: @NathanOliver In practice I will iterate over the integers calling __builtin_ctz on each one.  If it is more than  64 bits will it give the same answer?

Comment: I have no idea.  My idea didn't pan out though so I guess it doesn't matter, sorry.

Comment: @doynax Thanks. Should `__builtin_clzll` give the same answer whether you use `long long` (at least 64 bits) or `int64_t` (exactly 64 bits)?

Comment: @eleanora: No, I suppose you'll need something along the lines of `__builtin_clzll(value) + 64 - CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned long long)` if you should manage to encounter a platform with `long long` wider than 64-bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`uint64_t` is:

> **Optional**: These typedefs are not defined if no types with such
>   characteristics exist.

as you can read in the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/).

---

From [Should I use long long or int64_t for portable code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468281/should-i-use-long-long-or-int64-t-for-portable-code):

> The types `long long` and `unsigned long long` are standard C and standard C++ types each with at least 64 bits. All compilers I'm aware of provide these types, except possibly when in a `-pedantic` mode but in this case `int64_t` or `uint64_t` won't be available with pre-C++ 2011 compilers, either. "

---

What date did g++/clang support `long long`/`int64_t` from?

> Since [GCC 4.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) (aka [March 5, 2008](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/)).

As David Álvarez mentioned.

Comment: What date did g++/clang support long long/int64_t from?

Comment: @eleanora [Since GCC 4.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) (aka [March 5, 2008](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/))

Comment: @DavidÁlvarez Thanks. It looks like int64_t support came a little later than long long.

Comment: @eleanora Yes because long long int was added for C99 and int64_t was an optional C++11 feature

Comment: @DavidÁlvarez Re: int64_t, it looks like gcc 4.5 added a builtin <stdint.h> for platforms where libc doesn't have one, but that was in 2010